# jquery ui resizable change height only

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using jquery resizable and dragging up. It changes the height as correct but also the `top` value.

Changing the top misplaces my element which is absolutely positioned. How do I get it to not change the top value and change the height only?

Thanks

Comment: can you give a jsfiddle example?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick, not sure why "n" handle forces the attribute "top" to be overwritten, but I fixed the same behaviour by simply setting top: auto; when the resize event fires.

```
        $("#element_to_resize").resizable({ handles: 'n' }).bind("resize", function (e, ui) {
            $(this).css("top", "auto");
        });
```